# EPGLTransitionView

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode3.2

Most of you should know the the cool EPGLTransitionView for flip paging store in the github repository:

https://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView

It is done in opengl but it only works in one landscape direction.

Anyone knows or can give me a tip how can I implement easily the rest of devitation orientations?

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The `EPGLTransitionView` uses `FlipTransitions` to make the animations. Here the orientation is hardcoded, you need to change this to your current orientation device.

Overwrite the `setupTransition` method of `FlipForward` and `FlipBackward` classes:

```
- (void)setupTransition {
NSUInteger rotationFactor = 0;
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
switch (orientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        rotationFactor = 0;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        rotationFactor = 90;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        rotationFactor = 180;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        rotationFactor = 270;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
// Setup matrices
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(rotationFactor, 0, 0, -1);
glFrustumf(-0.1, 0.1, -0.1333, 0.1333, 0.4, 100.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();    
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
f = 0;}
```